# UISlider core data programing

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data

Im working on a simple "point based" app.

under settings the user set´s the number of points needed to get a "goodie"  using a slider.

```
-(IBAction) sliderChanged: (id)sender {

    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *) sender;
    int progressAsInt =(int)(slider.value +0.5);
    NSString *newText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",progressAsInt];
    sliderLabel.text = newText;
    [newText release];
```

this works fine, but how so i store  the slider value in my core data model, and how do make my slider show the stored value when view loads.

hope u can help me out :-D

Hey gerry3  i found my error.  i never set my toD-object in my settingsViewController, with:

```
       NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription
                    entityForName:@"ToDo" inManagedObjectContext:_context]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *array = [_context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (array == nil)
{
    // Deal with error...
}

if(array.count > 0){
    toDo = [array objectAtIndex:0];
} else { // no one to fetch - generate one
    toDo = [NSEntityDescription
            insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ToDo"
            inManagedObjectContext:_context];

[toDo retain];
```

your code works like a charm .....

Thanks
Skov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is that Core Data stores numeric attributes (e.g. integers, floats, etc) as NSNumber objects.

Say that your entity is called Record and it has a integer attribute called 'progress'.

If you create a managed object instance of Record named 'record', then you can set its progress like this:

```
[record setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:progressAsInt] forKey:@"progress"];
```

When you want to update your view with the value from your model (usually in `viewWillAppear:`), you can get its progress like this:

```
NSNumber *progressNumber = [record valueForKey:@"progress"];
slider.value = [progressNumber floatValue];
```

Alternatively, if you generate the class files for the Record entity, you can just do:

```
record.progress = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:progressAsInt];
```

and:

```
slider.value = [record.progress floatValue];
```

Comment: Thanks  gerry3     but if i  close my app, and restarts the app, the slider go´s back to 1, if i add  - (void)save {
  int progressAsInt =(int)(pointSlider.value +0.5);
 toDo.goodiesPoints = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:progressAsInt];

Comment: Are you using Apple's (or someone else's) example code to set up and save the Core Data stack? Are you creating the toDo managed object by inserting it into the managed object context?

Comment: toDo is a property of the Class of ToDo entity with goodiesPoints attribute. im using the one from template, so Apples with out the _ after NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

Comment: toDo is an instance of the ToDo class. How are you creating toDo?

Comment: @class ToDo;

@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>{
  
 ToDo *toDo;

Comment: Ok, you declared toDo as an ivar (instance variable). Where do you set it? (e.g. `toDo = <creation code here>`).